# IPhone App Manual Install with Settings Bundle

Tags: iphone, installation, manual, settings.bundle

I have a problem that i can't solve, i have a little application that uses a settings bundle, i don't have the apple license developer, so to test the app in a real iphone, i have to manual install (copy the application to the applications folder and set the permissions). 
After refreshing the GUI I can run the application fine, but the settings doesn't show in the settings and my application can't read them...

How can i add the settings to the settings of the iphoen?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your developing on a jailbroken iPhone since your installing without codesigning...
Have a look at [this](http://modmyi.com/forums/file-mods/22453-how-make-custom-menus-preferences-app-custom-preferences.html), which is a tutorial on how to use [PreferenceLoader](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/PreferenceLoader).